# Is it safe if a qml singleton is depended on another qml singleton

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.4

I have the following file structure:

```
\qml
  someQmlFile.qml
  someOtherQmlfilw.qml
  \Singletons
    firstSingleton.qml
    secondSingleton.qml
```

I need to access some of the properties in `firstSingleton.qml` within `secondSingleton.qml`. How is the order of singleton file creation defined? I tried looking into the docs, but I didn't find any specific information regarding this issue.

Edit 1: Some clarifications

`firstSingleton.qml`:

```
QtObject {
  readonly property int value: 5
}
```

`secondSingleton.qml`:

```
QtObject {
  readonly property int value: firstSingleton.value + 10
}
```

What happens if on startup `sencondSingleton` is created before `firstSingleton`? Should Qt handle this somehow in a clever way, or should I be able to somehow specify the order of creation of my singletons?

Comment: I don't get your question, as Qt simply don't care about how you structure your file in folder. As far as I understand, you can load the qml file into QQmlComponent and traverse through it's items.

Comment: @dangsonbk: I have updated my question with a dummy example. Hope this explains what I am trying to ask. You are probably right, that my file structure doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: I don't think you can directly access the value of other qml screen like that, but there are ways I know to do.:
1. Signals and slots /
2. Access attribute and update from C++. /
Hope this help